# I'm getting `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in Docker Compose even though the two individual containers work when run separately

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

So I have a basic frontend and backend. The backend relies on some environment variables and this is my `docker-compose.yml`.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  backend:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./backend
    container_name: fastapi-api
    ports:
      - 80:80
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    container_name: vue-ui
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - backend
```

This gives me `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`, however when I ran the individual Dockerfiles for my frontend and backend, this goes smoothly

My frontend

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'frontend' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /frontend

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

My backend

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.8

LABEL maintainer="Sebastian Ramirez <tiangolo@gmail.com>"

WORKDIR /backend

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
```

This is what I see from running `docker ps`
[image]

This is what's happening, frontend requests are being sent to the wrong place
[image]

I want it to go here
[image]

So requests should go to port 80 not port 8000

This is what I see from dev tools
[image]

However this is my code

```js
axios
          .post(`http://127.0.0.1:80/city/`, {
            city_name: this.current_city
          })
```

Where are the extra 0s coming from?

This is what happens when I ran the two containers separately
[image]

Comment: Was container started correctly? Execute `docker ps` command to inspect created containers.

Comment: When I run `docker-compose up`, after that I ran `docker ps` I found two containers as expected

Comment: Can you access the backend through `localhost:80`?

Comment: No luck with that as well

Comment: can you please shutdown the docker-compose deployment (`docker-compose down`) and verify that all containers are stopped (`docker ps -a` -> should not list any `fastapi-api`, if one is present, delete it: `docker rm <container-id>`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the `docker ps` output I would guess that you have by accident switched ports for backend and frontend in configuration. Frontend has unmapped port `80` and backend has unmapped port `8080`.

Try this one:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  backend:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./backend
    container_name: fastapi-api
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    container_name: vue-ui
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - backend
```

Comment: From OP: "*... when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`...*" - Frontend seems to be running on port `8080` on purpose.

Comment: From OP's screenshot you can see that frontend container is listening on 80 port inside container and backend on 8080. Those ports are unmapped, so I am guessing it was by accident switched.

Comment: Ah! Good catch!

Comment: So now I can view the frontend but why is it sending redirecting from the frontend requests to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` when my backend only works with `http://127.0.0.1:80/` (as tested with curl) just updated my post with what's happening

Comment: @A.K.M.Adib Where did you see port `8000`?

Comment: I don't know why it's going to port 8000, my frontend sends to a port on 80, I'm confused

Comment: I am guessing this is application related now. What can you see in browser network tab, to which URL is it sending requests?

Comment: I updated my post and the request URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/city/`, this is strange because when I ran the two containers separately it worked

Comment: I am not sure how are apps created or what is causing this, but URL in axios is not correct either, it should be `http://127.0.0.1:8080/city/`.

Comment: I made the change but I still get redirected